# ResourceAccessException with SocketException: Connection reset, when making a REST Call through a proxy

Tags: java, spring, proxy, resttemplate

## Context

I have a backend service that makes a REST call (*<target-url>*) to a different system. The other system is only reachable through a proxy and needs to security tokens (cookies).

## Implementation

I use a RestTemplateCustomizer to set the proxy, like this:

```
static class ProxyCustomizer implements RestTemplateCustomizer {

    private final HttpHost proxy;

    ProxyCustomizer(final HttpHost proxy) {
      this.proxy = proxy;
    }

    @Override
    public void customize(final RestTemplate restTemplate) {
      final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setRoutePlanner(new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(this.proxy) {

        @Override
        public HttpHost determineProxy(final HttpHost target, final HttpRequest request, final HttpContext context)
            throws HttpException {
          return super.determineProxy(target, request, context);
        }

      }).build();
      restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient));
    }
  }
```

The REST template is called like this:

```
    final HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("<proxy-url>");
    this.restTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder(new ProxyCustomizer(proxy)).build();
```

I'm using these header:

```
    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(ACCEPT));
    headers.set(HttpHeaders.COOKIE, securityToken);
    return headers;
```

## Exception

All I can access for a log is the following:

```
Failed to get Information from Service.org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: 
    I/O error on GET request for "<target-url>": Connection reset; 
    nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

Without the proxy I got the following exception:

```
Failed to get Information from Service.org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: 
    I/O error on GET request for "<target-url>": <target-host>: Name or service not known; 
    nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: <target-host>: Name or service not known
```

I would appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work.

My solution was not to use a RestRemplateCustomizer but to set the proxy when creating the http client.

```
    try {
      clientBuilder.setSSLContext(SSLContext.getDefault());
    } catch (final NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
      log.error("Error while setting SSL Context");
      throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
    }

    if (null != configuration && null != configuration.getProxyHost()) {
      final HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(configuration.getProxyHost(), configuration.getProxyPort());
      clientBuilder.setRoutePlanner(new PcssProxyRoutePlanner(proxy));
      clientBuilder.setSSLHostnameVerifier((hostname, session) -> true);
    } else {
      clientBuilder.setRoutePlanner(new SystemDefaultRoutePlanner(new DefaultProxySelector()));
    }
```